# how can set padding on poly line in google map in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-polyline

i try to draw poly line between 
two or more location  on  google  map 
but  i

need  poly  line like as shown in image

correct but it can show  map like wrong
first image is wrong

second image is correct 
how can i set poly line like correct image

how i can set margin or padding between lat long and poly line on google map

[image: wrong image] 
[image: correct image]

my code is:

```
    public void mSetUpMap() {

    googleMap.clear();

    if (AppUtil.itinerary != null)
        str = AppUtil.itinerary.getItinerary();
    if (AppUtil.itinerary != null)
        shareUrl = AppUtil.itinerary.getShareUrl();
    Log.e("Ittt", "" + AppUtil.itinerary.getItinerary());
    ((HomeActivity) getActivity()).setTexrViewText(str);
    poiList.clear();
    poiList = AppUtil.itinerary.getPoiList();
    List<Marker> markersList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (POI item : poiList) {
        Marker m1 = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new 
   LatLng(item.getLatitude(), item.getLongitude()))
                .title(item.getName()).anchor(0.39f, 0.39f)

 .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(getCustomMarker
 ((R.drawable.m2red), item.getName()))));
  }

    googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
            ValueAnimator ani = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1); 
            ani.setDuration(2000);
            ani.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() 
   {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    marker.setAlpha((float) animation.getAnimatedValue());
                }

            });
            ani.start();

            return true;
        }
    });
    /**create for loop for get the latLngbuilder from the marker list*/
    builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    for (Marker m : markersList) {
        builder.include(m.getPosition());
    }

    int padding = 200;

    LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();

    cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);

    googleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapLoaded() {
            /**set animated zoom camera into map*/
            googleMap.animateCamera(cu);
            PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
            for (POI item : poiList) {
                polylineOptions.add(new LatLng(item.getLatitude(), 
        item.getLongitude()));
            }
            polylineOptions.width(3);
            polylineOptions.getPoints();
            polylineOptions.getPoints();
            polylineOptions.color(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
            Polyline line = googleMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);

        }
      });
    }
```

Comment: Have you found any solution?